# Program to calculate average of five numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I am a beginner in java and wrote a program to calculate the average of five numbers. But i don't know why it came up with an error. So what can I do to resolve this.

```
public static void main(String args[]){
  int nums[]=new int[5];
  nums[]={1,3,5,7,9};       
  int num2=0,i;
  for(i=0;i<=4;i++){
    num2=nums[i]+num2;
  }
  System.out.println(num2/5);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @AndyTurner why don't you close this question?

Comment: Also note that you're using **integer** arithmetic. It doesn't matter for the specific values in your array, but it would matter for any set of values not quite so carefully chosen. (Say, `1,2,5,9,10`, which averages to 5.4 but would yield 5 in your code.)

Comment: @xenteros unless I'm marking it as a duplicate, I can't use the close hammer. I can only (and have) voted to close as off-topic because "questions asking "why isn't this code working...""..

Comment: @AndyTurner Sorry, didn't know that - I thought that "close hammer" is ultimate machine.

Comment: @xenteros no problem :)

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign a value to an array using *initializer notation* you after have declared it. (The hint is in the name - you can only use it to *initialize* the array).

Instead of

```
int nums[]=new int[5];
nums[]={1,3,5,7,9};
```

use

```
int nums[] = {1,3,5,7,9};
```

You can use:

```
nums = new int[] {1,3,5,7,9};
```

but you don't need to assign a value to the array first using `int nums[] = new int[5];` - `int nums[];` is sufficient.

---

Also, it is generally considered better to use `int[] nums` instead of `int nums[]`: the "array-ness" is part of the type, not the variable name, so keep the `[]` with the `int`.

(The `int nums[]` form was included in early versions of Java to make the language more familiar to C/C++ programmers, and we're now stuck with it.)

Comment: Thanks! I got it now